# How to solve logical vector "TRUE" in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, business-objects

The question is: How many households live in area 2, earn more than 20k, and have purchased more than 30 units of pasta over the whole time period?

I tried

```
pasta  %>%
  filter(AREA=="2") %>% group_by(HHID) %>% 
  summarise(buy2= sum(PASTA), INCOME) %>% 
  summarise(income2 = INCOME > "20000" && buy2 > "30")

# run and show 
  `summarise()` has grouped output by 'HHID'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
  A tibble: 403 x 2
    HHID income2
   <int> <lgl>  
 1    10 TRUE   
 2    16 TRUE   
 3    17 FALSE  
 4    29 TRUE   
 5    30 FALSE  
 6    31 FALSE  
 7    36 TRUE   
 8    42 FALSE  
 9    47 TRUE   
10    60 TRUE   
# … with 393 more rows
```

How can I count the 'TRUE'?

Comment: The argument is `.groups` and it should be `.groups = 'drop'` instead of `.group(HHID)`

Comment: Hard to help you if you dont share the data

Comment: redgoose, welcome to SO! Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for great discussions on how to make a question *reproducible*, specifically providing usable, unambiguous sample data (`dput(.)`).

Comment: I can share the dataset, please let me know where to upload.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to count the logical, use `sum`.  In addition, replace the `&&` with `&` and remove the quotes around the numeric values

```
...
 summarise(Count = sum(INCOME > 20000 & buy2 > 30, na.rm = TRUE), 
        .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

Comment: @redgoose I would just load `library(dplyr);library(ggplot2)` on a fresh R session and do this again.  Loading tidyverse implies a lot of packages and that may be not needed in this code.  In addition, some packages have functions that can mask the dplyr functions